# Iteratively remove elements of a list based on calculation with adjacent list items Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I have a list of tuples (representing x-y coordinates), and I want the coordinate to be removed if it is too close to the preceding coordinate (Euclidean distance). If it meets the criteria and is removed, I want the original coordinate to be then checked against its "new" adjacent coordinate, and then this removed if it is still too close. I need this process repeated until the coordinates are the required distance apart. I then want to move on to the next coordinate (which may have originally been multiple coordinates ahead, without deletions).

example:

```
coordinateList=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,...]

if |x1-x2|<d:
    remove x2
if |x1-x3|<d:
    remove x3
...
until |x1-xn|>=d
then keep xn
coordinateList=[x1,xn,xn+1,xn+2...]
then
if |xn-xn+1|<d:
    remove xn+1
etc.
etc.
```

I have tried :

```
length=len(coordinateList)
while i < length:
    if math.sqrt((coordinateList[i][0]-coordinateList[i+1][0])**2+(coordinateList[i][1]-coordinateList[i+1][1])**2)<50:
        coordinateList.remove(coordinateList[i+1])
        length-=1
    else:
        i+=1
```

and i get my original list back.

I have also tried:

```
for i in range(1,maxRows):
    j=i+1
    norm=math.sqrt((coordinateList[i][0]-coordinateList[j][0])**2+(coordinateList[i][1]-coordinateList[j][1])**2)
    if norm<50:
        j=j+1
    else:    
        coordinateList2.append(coordinateList[j])
```

but this only applies my criteria to list items that were adjacent in the original list.

I'm really struggling here, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please provide a clear, reproducible, example of input and the matching expected output? What you want is currently unclear, you mention a "*list of tuples*" but show a list of x values.

Comment: Repeatedly removing elements from the list will be O(n²); instead (and simpler) add far-enough-apart elements to a new list, this way you only have to compare the current element to the last element in the new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NB. I am using the absolute distance and a `<=`/`>` comparison to make demo simple, but you can use `math.sqrt(…)` and `<`/`>=` if needed.*

Your expected loop is equivalent to:

```
coordinateList=[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 15, 15.1, 15.2]
d = 1

if len(coordinateList)>1:
    i = 1
    while i < len(coordinateList):
        if abs(coordinateList[i]-coordinateList[i-1]) <= d:
            coordinateList.pop(i)
        else:
            i += 1

print(coordinateList)
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 8, 10, 15]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved my problem. I think my main stumbling block across the various scripts I wrote were to do with not defining "i" before my while loops.

Comment: @Jack you're welcome. Note that I used the same approach as yours, but as commented removing a value from a list is `O(n)`, so a more efficient approach would be to append the valid values in a new list ;)

Answer (score 1):

A variant of your last approach, creating a new list, but comparing to the last element in the *new* list instead of keeping track of the last "good" element in the old list:

```
coordinateList2 = []
for x in coordinateList:
    if not coordinateList2 or distance(x, coordinateList2[-1]) >= 50:
        coordinateList2.append(x)
```

Here, `distance` is the function comparing the two elements. The current element `x` is just compared to the last element in the new list `coordinateList2` (if there is any). This is somewhat simpler, and should also be faster as it does not repeatedly `remove` or `pop` from the middle of the list.

Comment: Yes I thought I read `coordinateList`, not `coordinateList2` and the output was incorrect ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dist(x1,x2) function and renaming coordinateList as l:

```py
idxs = [0] # Store indices of the final result
i = 0 # l[i] = First (x,y)
for j in range(1, len(l)): # l[j] = Second (x,y)
  if dist(l[i], l[j]) >= d:  
    idxs.append(j)
    i = j
result = [l[i] for i in idxs]
```